# Limitation in adding data to the database based on the date and frequency

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form image below where the user can add their session:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD8Ie.png)

We can add the session now and already working, however, the limitation has to take place since every student has its frequency that should be seen depending on how many times per week. So for example in the image I have there, the student should only be added once per week and the user should not be allowed to add more in the same week. From Sunday to Saturday the session for that student should only be added once and if the session frequency is 2x, then the user can add 2 sessions for that student.

I haven't tried any code for the limitation but so far this is the code that I have.

```js
<script>

const getSeconds = s => s.split(":").reduce((acc, curr) => acc * 60 + +curr, 0);
const twoDigit = s => s < 10 ? '0'+s : s;
const timeToMins = s => s.split(':')[0]*60 + +s.split(':')[1];

const formatTime = s => {
  let hours = Math.floor(s / 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor(s % 60);
  return `${twoDigit(minutes)}`
}

const updateInput = () => {
  let start = getSeconds(document.getElementById("stime").value);
  let end = getSeconds(document.getElementById("etime").value);
  let res = Math.abs(end - start);
  let diff = formatTime(res) 
  document.getElementById("time").value = diff;
}

const updateEnd = () => {
  let start = getSeconds(document.getElementById("stime").value);
  let diff = document.getElementById("time").value
  let end = formatTime(start+timeToMins(diff))
  document.getElementById("etime").value = end;
}

updateInput()
</script>
```

```html
<form action="code.php" method="post">
      

                                <div class="row">  

                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="form-floating" required>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['nycid'];?>" name="nycid" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="John" readonly="readonly">
                                        <label for="floatingInputGrid">NYCID</label>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['firstname'];?>" name="fname" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Firstname</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['lastname'];?>" name="lname" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Lastname</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['dob'];?>" name="dob" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Date of Birth</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="row mt-2">  

                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="form-floating" required>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="District <?=$studentinfo['dist'];?>" name="dist" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="John" readonly="readonly">
                                        <label for="floatingInputGrid">Service District</label>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['stype'];?>" name="service" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Related Service</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['adbn'];?> @ <?=$studentinfo['pldbn'];?>" name="location" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Location of Services Provided</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['provider'];?>" name="provider" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Provider</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  
                                </div>

                                <div class="row mt-2">  

                                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="form-floating" required>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['freq'];?>" name="freq" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="John" readonly="readonly">
                                        <label for="floatingInputGrid">Frequency</label>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['dur'];?>" name="dur" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Duration</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['gsize'];?>" name="gsize" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Group Size</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm">
                                      <div class="form-floating" required>
                                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$studentinfo['language'];?>" name="language" id="floatingInputGrid" placeholder="Doe" readonly="readonly">
                                          <label for="floatingInputGrid">Language</label>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>

                                </div>

                                    <div class="row mt-2">
                                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="form-floating">
                                                <input id="serviceDate" class="form-control" required name="sessiondate" type="date" />
                                                <label for="startDate">Session Date</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm">
                                            <div class="form-floating">
                                                <select class="form-select" id="floatingSelectGrid" required name="mode" aria-label="Floating label select example">
                                                    <option selected>--</option>
                                                    <option value="Audio & Video">Audio & Video</option>
                                                    <option value="Audio Only">Audio Only</option>
                                                    <option value="In-Person">In-Person</option>
                                                </select>
                                                <label for="floatingSelectGrid">Delivery Mode</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="form-floating">
                                                <input id="stime" class="form-control" required name="stime" type="time" value="12:00" onchange="updateInput()"/>
                                                <label for="stime">Start Time</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                                            <div class="form-floating">
                                                <input id="etime" class="form-control" required name="etime" type="time" value="12:30" onchange="updateInput()"/>
                                                <label for="etime">End Time</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                   

                                        <div class="col col-sm">
                                            <div class="form-floating">
                                                <input id="time" onkeyup="updateEnd()" class="form-control"  name="time" type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
                                                <label for="time" >Time</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
            

            <div class="flex-btn mt-5">
            <button type="submit" name="add_session" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end">ADD SESSION</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: How do you prefer the user be prevented from adding additional sessions? Disable the Session Date field? ..and disable the Add Session button? Disable the Add Session box altogether? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think I would prefer to disable the add session button and an alert saying that they are exceedingly adding sessions.

Comment: I see you have a "frequency" variable available. Do you have a max frequency variable to compare it to?

Comment: We have a maximum of 5x weekly.

Comment: 5 is fixed for every student? Then does this work? `<button type="submit" name="add_session" class="btn <? if ( 5 === $studentinfo['freq'] ) { echo "disablebtn "; } ?> btn-primary btn-sm float-end">...` "disablebtn" is assumed to be a CSS selector name that disables the button, such as `disablebtn { cursor: not-allowed; }`

Comment: Sometimes we have make-up sessions that are usually 10x up to "90x in total" that will be seen under frequency. This case should not have a limit weekly but users cannot add sessions on the same student per day. Does that make sense? It's blowing my mind. =D

Comment: The code above will disable the button if the frequency is 5x, right?